# Get index that contains ".txt" in the list without using loop in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, list, java-stream, indexof

I would like to get the first index of a string that contains a `".txt"` in the list using JAVA. without doing any loop. Because I have lots of value in File like :

```
["sample.txt", "sample.csv","sample.docx","sample","sample.xlsx","sample2.txt, ...];
```

I only need the index of **"sample.txt"**

```
List<String> files = Arrays.asList(fileList).stream()
                             .map(x -> x.getAbsolutePath())
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
index = files.indexOf(?);
```

Comment: Since you are already using streams, why don't you try using filter and findFirst?

Comment: What is the type of `fileList` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to use :

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(fileList);

String first = list.stream(fileList)
        .filter(x -> x.endsWith(".txt")) // or contains if the .txt can be in the middle
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null); // you can even throw and exception using orElseThrow

// to get the index you can use
int index = list.indexOf(first);
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thank you so much!